# Flattening JSON document in Cosmos DB

Tags: json, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have a nested JSON with arrays. This raw json gets stored in cosmos db as-is.
Now I have to unnest some of the arrays within this JSON and fetch specific fields, some of these fields will form header level details and rest will form line item level details.
With separate queries(by flattening required arrays) I can find these fields(header, line item) separately. For e.g. below is just some of the required fields in header, which I get as output of one query after flattening one of the arrays within the json.

```json
[
    {
        "identifier": "639",
            "owner": "ABC"
            "recepient": "XYZ"
        }
    },
    {
        "identifier": "640",
            "owner": "TESTOWNER"
            "recipient": "TESTrecipient"
        }
    }
]
```

If I combine unnesting of different arrays in single query, it becomes a cartesian product.

Not sure how to combine all these fields(header, line item) together and pass it to the consuming application as one JSON response.Is cosmos db stored procedure an option to combine these fields together by unnesting required arrays within json.

Looking forward to hearing some suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can always us the JOIN operator to get yourself into arrays and I don not think you need to use any Cosmos SPR to achieve what you need.